# Mock a shell command in a script called from Python subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess

I have a situation where I need to mock an executable (pip) with a shell script I wrote (mock_pip) for a unit test, so I use the subprocess module to get access to the shell. I've tried a lot of things like:

```
subprocess.Popen("alias pip='/some/dir/mock_pip'", shell=True) # Create alias
subprocess.Popen("pip", shell=True) # Try to use new alias, but still points towards real pip instead

subprocess.Popen("alias pip='/some/dir/mock_pip'"; "pip", shell=True)
# Once again it uses the real pip instead of mock
```

I even tried this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842862/creating-command-line-alias-with-python) by changing the `~/.bashrc` file in my home directory (also during the unit test using subprocess) but that doesn't work either.
I'm imagining the problem is that subprocess erases the environment after every command that is called, meaning my alias doesn't exist when I try calling it.

How can I cause `mock_pip` to be used instead of `pip` in a bash script started from my Python process?

Comment: Your posted code contains syntax errors. Maybe you could get it to work when setting `shell=True`, but I guess it will not carry over for different popens. Why not make a python function that calls the appropriate pip?

Comment: `subprocess` does not erase the environment, the operating system does.  Add the alias to `.bashrc`, but aliases are not normally expanded in scripts, they are a support nightmare and generally considered to be bad practice (functions are preferred), you have to `shopt -s expand_aliases` (again, in `.bashrc`).

Comment: @syntonym Sorry, I forgot to proof read my code, but I did have `shell=True`. What do you mean create a function to call the appropriate pip though?

Comment: Every time you call `subprocess.Popen`, that's a new subprocess. A **new, completely independent** subprocess. How is a later subprocess supposed to know what a previous one, which already exited, did to its state before exiting?

Comment: Re: your `~/.bashrc`, the issue there is that it's only automatically invoked for **interactive** shells, and `subprocess.Popen(..., shell=True)` creates a noninteractive shell.

Comment: @cdarke They seem to cause a lot of head ache for nothing. I heard another way to "mock" the executable would be to change the PATH of pip to that of mock_pip, but then again, wouldn't that be erased after the subprocess call also?

Comment: You'd put the updated environment with the PATH change in your `subprocess.Popen()` argument list itself. `subprocess.Popen(..., env={'PATH': '/directory/with/new/stub:' + os.environ['PATH']})`

Comment: What @CharlesDuffy said :-)  But also remember that you can set/change environment variables in python using `os.environ` which will be inherited by the child processes created by `subprocess`.  `os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ':whatever'`

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest modifying your question such that it asks what you're **really** interested in knowing -- ie. how to mock a shell command when called from Python's `subprocess.Popen`, rather than about alias persistence.

Comment: BTW, as an aside, do you have a compelling reason for `shell=True`? You shouldn't actually need it here -- both the answers I gave will work if you invoke `mpp` with `shell=False`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In my actual script I don't call `subprocess` every single time, I define a function that returns the output of `subprocess` and call that function throughout the entire script. Most of the commands (around half) require `shell=True` so I added it to the `subprocess` call to generalize it for any command.

Comment: The thing is that `shell=True` has some serious side effects -- most particularly, if you're passing filenames or user-controlled parameters on argument lists it requires a great deal of sophistication to avoid shell injection attacks via crafted filenames. It may take some work to avoid, but if your work is at all security-sensitive, that work is worthwhile.

Comment: If you opened a question asking how to rewrite wrapper X to allow a calling convention that covers use cases A, B and C while not requiring `shell=True`, I'd be happy to take a shot at it. :) [though perhaps not immediately; I'm about to be leaving for an appointment].

Comment: ...using `shell=True` safely with arbitrary arguments requires hacks like: `subprocess.Popen(['outputFile=$1; shift; exec >"$outputFile"; exec ./script-here "$@"', outputFile, arg1, arg2], shell=True)`, to keep those arguments (list items other than the first) out-of-band from the content parsed as code (the first item passed). I'm willing to hazard you're not currently doing that work.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I always hear about how dangerous it is to use `shell=True`, but the commands I run are all hard-coded and shouldn't really pose a threat seeing as they don't actually manipulate anything (at least I don't think it's a threat). Then again, I still have a lot to learn about the entire `subprocess` module haha

Comment: Are the *arguments* to those commands also hardcoded? And if they're hardcoded, what do you need a shell to interpret for you (thus, why do you need `shell=True` at all?) -- if it's redirections like `>outputFile`, you can do that with arguments to `Popen`, which you can pass through your wrapper with `**kwargs`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yea, all the arguments are hardcoded also, the user can't input anything to change the script. And I tested it with `shell=False`, but it fails on simple commands like `chmod 755 somefile`.

Comment: With `shell=False`, you'll want to use `['chmod', '755', '--', 'somefile']`, not `chmod 755 somefile`. That's a feature, not a bug -- it means your `somefile` name can contain whitespace or literal quotes or `$(rm -rf $HOME)` or anything else and it'll still be treated as a filename and won't break your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal here is to provide a mock implementation of pip, you can do that in a few ways:

- Generate it as an exported function
- Set a PATH value pointing to a directory containing wrapper as an executable script

---

The former is shell-version-specific, so we'll cover the latter first:

```
subprocess.Popen('pip', env={'PATH': '/path/to/mock/dir:' + os.environ['PATH']})
```

...where your `/path/to/mock/dir` is a location with a `pip` executable that performs your desired operations.

---

The latter, for post-shellshock upstream bash releases (and prior versions of bash with shellshock fixes compatible with the protocol for exported functions that upstream arrived on):

```
env = dict(os.environ)
env['BASH_FUNC_pip%%'] = '() { mock_pip "$@"; }'
subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', 'pip'], shell=False, env=env)
```

Note the `shell=False` here, with the explicit `['bash', '-c', ...]` -- that ensures that it's `bash` (which will honor the exported function) rather than the default shell `sh` invoked.

Comment: I set the path to the directory where my mock pip is located and it uses the mock now instead of the real pip. But there's still a problem (and I probably should've mentioned this earlier but didn't think it would affect anything), but the pip I'm trying to mock is inside of bash script.. (Sorry again) So basically i have the script `mpp' which contains `pip` commands, and those are the commands I want to mock. I tried `subprocess.Popen('mpp', env={'PATH': '/path/to/mock/dir:' + os.environ['PATH']})` but it uses the real pip (located in bin) instead of my mock pip. Sorry if this is confusing..

Comment: Hmm. That should work, barring interference (such as something else being executed that modifies the inherited PATH). If you have your script run `declare -p PATH`, does it print the value with the mock directory first? If that script runs `type pip >&2`, what's the result?

Comment: The  `declare -p PATH` does in fact give me the path to the mock's directory, so exactly as set by the `env` key in `subprocess`. As for the `type pip >&2`, it points directly to my mock pip script I created so `/path/to/mock/dir/pip`. Even though, when I run my `mpp` script, it uses the real pip and I can confirm since my mock pip has a counter which doesn't get updated. But the mock does get called when I run a simple `pip` command through `subprocess` since the counter actually updates.

Comment: ...those `declare -p PATH` and `type pip` commands being directly before where `mpp` calls the real `pip`? Next step is probably to run `mpp` with `set -x` and inspect the actual commands.

Comment: That said, it's all guesswork until you provide a reproducer.

Comment: Hahaha I figured out what the problem was, the `mpp` command I gave skipped the pip command because it wasn't getting the proper arguments so it just never called pip at all. I tried a few other commands and it does actually call the mock. Thank you so much for helping me through this!